# In PySide, detect mouse movement and mouse button state within a QGraphicsRectItem, without it being selected

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsitem

I have a program somewhat similar to Microsoft Paint, and I'm working on implementing canvas resizing. I need to detect if the mouse cursor has moved into resizing range, and if the left mouse button is held down while the mouse is being moved. I have a `QGraphicsRectItem` set up as my canvas, and **I want to detect mouse movement and mouse button state in my `QGraphicsRectItem`, without it being selected**.

I've been using `QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent` for detecting if the cursor is within resizing range or not, but when the left mouse button is held down, `hoverMoveEvent` is no longer triggered.

There's `mouseMoveEvent`, but [as the docs say](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent):

> If you do receive this event, you can be certain that this item also
>   received a mouse press event, and that *this item is the current mouse
>   grabber*.

In my program, it's impractical for my canvas to be the current mouse grabber when resizing. I may have other objects that need to retain their selection states while the canvas is being resized.

I realize I could do this in the `QGraphicsScene` containing my `QGraphicsRectitem`, but to avoid interdependence between them, I'd like to be able to do this all in my `QGraphicsRectItem`.

So my question is: How, if possible, do I detect mouse movement and mouse button states on a `QGraphicsRectitem` without the it being selected?